# .NET HealthCheck throws unhandled exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, health-check

I recently added Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks to my .NET with react application, but if I want to call my URL for the healthcheck I get the Error: "An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request."

My Healthcheck looks like this:

```cs
app.UseHealthChecks("/api/monitoring", new HealthCheckOptions
        {
            ResponseWriter = async (context, report) =>
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                var response = HealthCheckUtils.CreateResponse(report);
                var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(response, new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web));
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(jsonString);
            }
        });
```

Does anyone encounter the same problem and knows how to fix it?

If you need anymore information, please let me know.

Comment: I would expect details to be written in the server log. Have you looked at that?

Comment: @JonSkeet only error: "An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. An exception was thrown attempting to display the error page."

Comment: In that case I'd run it in the debugger, to try to get at the *actual* exception. Without those details, there's very little chance of resolving the issue. (You should also update the question to give that extra information - both that you've looked in the server log, and that an exception was thrown attempting to display the error page.)